# Spectrum Analysis

Tags: power, cellphone, spectrum-analyzer

I am working on a project where I need to measure the power density in milliwatts per centimeter squared (mW/cm²) from several different transmitting smart phone models.

But the spectrum analyzer I am using displays the power in decibel (dBm), and what I need is power in watts (W),  so that I will be able to calculate the power density (mW/cm²).

How do I convert power in decibel (dBm) to power in watts (W)?

Comment: What part is unclear? Decibels in general or what dBm means? It's decibels compared to 1 milliwatt reference.

Comment: wikipedia is your friend, really.

Answer (score 2):

dBm means decibels referred to 1mW.
So you calculate \$10^{dBm_{value}/10}\$. Then you have your power in mW. Divide by 1000 and you have your power in W.

$$P = \frac{1}{1000}\times 10^{\frac{dBm_{value}}{10}}$$

**Remark:** \$dBm_{value}\$ is the reading you get from the spectrum analyzer. Namely the power in dBm.